# ngx-bootstrap modal does not hide during test

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, angular-test, ngx-bootstrap-modal

In my Angular application, I'm writing some integration tests where I have an [ngx-bootstrap modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

In my integration tests, I'm testing a Component which contains a button that pops up a modal. Inside a modal, there is a "Save" button which is clicked during the tests.

Inside the Modal Component, the button triggers a method on click:
 `(click)=onSave()` and this is how the Modal Component looks like:

```
constructor(
  protected bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
) {}


onSave() {
  // do some stuff (NOTE: this part is actually executed during the test)
  this.bsModalRef.hide();
}
```

Everything works fine, except that the modal won't disappear. However the `onSave()` method is correctly executed.

That is very strange, because if I manually click on the button after the test has finished to run, it correctly hides the modal

But during the test, despite the button correctly receives the click and triggers the execution of the `onSave()` method, the modal does not disapper.

Note: there are no spies involved here and, since it's an integration test, I would prefer to not mock the `hide()` method but to actually make it work during the test and then assert that the modal has correctly disappeared together with the other side-effects of my custom `onSave()` method.

Comment: I believe there needs more details on the actual test, are you using the dispatcher api to trigger the click?

Comment: The problem is in [this method](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/blob/master/src/app/test-utils/editor-page-object.ts#L42)  that is used in [this test case](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/blob/master/src/app/components/editors/creature/creature-template-addon/creature-template-addon.integration.spec.ts#L140)

Comment: Looking quickly at your test there might be some async issues, have you tried with fakeasync along with tick()?

Comment: @Lucho when that is the case, you usually see the action completed (in this case the modal closed) then the test finishes executing. Instead, in my case the modal is still open even **after** the test completes. And even more strange is that, in the Chrome window of the karma tests, if I click on the button the modal closes correctly.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned due to js async nature, which “expect” is failing you exactly? Then I can write an example how I mean

Comment: @Lucho if I use for example `page.expectModalHidden()` in the test, it fails. I've tried also using `fakeAsync` and `tick()`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this instead in your clickElement method in test utilites "page-object.ts"

**from:**

```
clickElement(element: HTMLElement): void {
    element.click();
    this.fixture.detectChanges();
  }
```

**to:**

```
clickElement(element: HTMLElement): void {
    element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    this.fixture.detectChanges();
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-modal-test) of fakeAsync & tick() test

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it does not solve the issue :(

Comment: Did you try it with fakeAsync & tick?

Comment: Updated an example on the post

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the the modal reference in this.modalRef when you are showing it.

```
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.template, 
    { class: 'modal-md' });
}

save(){
     if (this.modalRef) {
        this.modalRef.hide();
     }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use this approach, instead of using the `bsModalRef`, but this does not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by first mocking setTimeout by

```
jasmine.clock().install()
```

Then call the:

```
this.modalService.hide(this.modalRef.id)
```

Then call (use 300 instead of 1 if you set animated to true in the options)

```
jasmine.clock().tick(1)
```

then close up with:

```
jasmine.clock().uninstall()
```

However when I use the this.modalRef.hide() it still does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Check in your browser console if you have an exception in your component. In my case, I had a "throw error" sample code inside an unused OnInit method.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented."); //<-- Culprit
}
```